# How to download all file content from a folder using wget and http

Tags: linux, unix, wget

I am trying to use `wget` and http to download all contents from folderAA below to directory *`/root/sstest`*

```
wget -r --directory-prefix="/root/sstest"  -o /root/sstest2.log http://site.com/folder1/folder2/folderAA/
```

When I submit the above command nothing is downloaded.

If I submit a `wget` request for a specific file from folderAA the file is actually downloaded to *`/root/sstest`*:

```
wget -r --directory-prefix="/root/sstest"  -o /root/sstest2.log http://site.com/folder1/folder2/folderAA/file.txt
```

Can someone tell me why I cannot download all file content from folderAA at once using the first `wget` request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can only work if the website supports directory listing. But, allowing that is considered a security hole and therefore most of the websites don't allow it and this it why you fail to do what you want